# How do I get Safari to autofill complete phone number with international acesss code in all phone number fields of any webform?

Tags: safari, autofill, phone-number

I want Safari to autofill my complete Finnish phone number, with a + and international access code on any site that requires a phonenumber in a webform.

I want Safari to autofill

```
+358451234567
```

instead it autofills

```
451234567
```

not even a `0` before which is required for the `45` which is the access code for mobile phone provider.

Helsinki number would be `+35891234567`, where `+` = country code prefix, `358` = countrycode Finland, `9` =  Helsinki, `1234567` = subscriber number.

Chrome on MacOS does it, fills in `+358451234567`. No problem.

I live, work and use websites in Finland, Europe. My phone number is Finnish. The websites are from all over the world. People in Europe write their phone umbers in the format `+1 234 56789012`

[Tel input autofill drops international prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67794921/15944277) tells how to change the code on webpage form, but I just want it to work on websites that I visit.

How do I do this? Any ideas? Any safe hacks for this?